# Creating a vertically collapsing and expanding html table

Tags: php, html, html-table, expand

I've got a php script that reads a file and generates a multi-page collection of tables and It's way to long to read easly. Is there any way to make each table collapse with the click of a small button leaving just the title bar for that table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the tables inside div elements and use jquery toggle on button click.

Here's an example for one table

HTML

```
<button id="hideshow">Helper</button>

<div id="hideshow1"><table><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   $( "#hideshow" ).click(function() {
      $( "#hideshow1" ).toggle("slow");      
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply but i'm having trouble getting it to work. Could you please make it into a single file?

Comment: You can include the javascript to your file by placing it between script tags <script> //the javascript code </script>. Don't forget to include the path to your jquery library or more simple just add these two lines before your script: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using CSS and JavaScript or JQuery. Define a div with a css class for example "collapsible" , put a link on your page and write a script that find any element of that class and hide/show them.

Answer (score 0):

create a div . place the table inside dat. provide overflow for the div and In script use Jquery Slidetoggle , show and hide function. You will get the necessary collapsing and expanding html table